# Como remover do DOM os "whitespace-only text node" que aparecem no HTML

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Parece que o HTML por default coloca um maldito"`whitespace-only text node`" entre os elementos do *inline level* com isso eu ganho uma "margem" entre os elementos que não consigo remover do DOM

Sei que existem soluções como colocando `display:flex` no Pai, ou colocando `float` nos elementos. Porém queria remover todos esses `whitespace node` de uma vez sem precisar dessas artifícios (ou de gambiarras como `margin-left:-4px`).

O FireFox mostra pelo DevTools esses nodes

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui tem um outro exemplo simples simulando o problema:

```css
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: palevioletred;
}
```

```html
<h2>Exemplo com Imagem</h2>
<div>
    <img src="http://unsplash.it/100/100" alt="">
    <img src="http://unsplash.it/100/100" alt="">
    <img src="http://unsplash.it/100/100" alt="">
    <img src="http://unsplash.it/100/100" alt="">
</div>
<br>
<img src="http://unsplash.it/100/100" alt=""><img src="http://unsplash.it/100/100" alt=""><img src="http://unsplash.it/100/100" alt=""><img src="http://unsplash.it/100/100" alt="">
<br>
<h2>Exemplo com ul/li { display:inline-block }</h2>
<ul>
    <li>item|</li>
    <li>item|</li>
    <li>item|</li>
    <li>item|</li>
</ul>
<br>
<ul>
    <li>item|</li><li>item|</li><li>item|</li><li>item|</li>
</ul>
```

Quando o Chrome renderiza o código ele coloca cada LI em uma linha, mesmo no código estando em uma linha só! Repare que mesmo o Chrome colocando cada LI em uma linha um exemplo continua buggado e o outro não...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Alguém tem alguma dica de como remover esse `whitespace-only text node` entre os elementos do DOM, mesmo que seja com jQuery ou algo do tipo?***

Link com artigo da Mozilla sobre o assunto: https://blog.nightly.mozilla.org/2016/10/17/devtools-now-display-white-space-text-nodes-in-the-dom-inspector/

Outro artigo interessante: https://medium.com/@patrickbrosset/when-does-white-space-matter-in-html-b90e8a7cdd33

Comment: Não é o HTML que insere, é você quebrando as linhas. Se omitir os espaços eles não aparecem no DOM. Remover depois é gambiarra da mesma forma. Ruim por ruim, pode por as quebras em comment   `<elemento><!-- quebra de linha --><elemento>` ou mesmo quebrar dentro da tag `<elemento quebradelinha><elemento>` - Aí fica feio só na estética, e não no DOM. Inclusive, a pergunta e a resposta simplesmente geram um trabalho desnecessário, pois o espaço atrapalha menos do que um código pra tirar, não consigo ver o sentido disso (mas ai ja é opinião minha).

Comment: @Bacco como vc falou cada um tem uma forma de lidar como esse "problema", mas quando vc faz um menu usando UL/LI por exemplo esse espaço pode facilmente quebrar o seu layout, além disso ele sempre se soma as margins laterais, tipo o margin-left:10px será na verdade os 10px mais esse nó...

Comment: Sei bem como é, tem posts no SOpt tratando disso justamente. Acho que eu mesmo devo ter respondido alguma. O fato é que estes nós só entram no DOM se o autor da página os colocar, o que eu questiono é justamente isso: dá menos trabalho e efeito colateral já não colocar no código, em vez de tirar depois. Lembrando que a indentação e formatação do HTML só serve para o autor da página, e não para o usuário final. Nada impede de publicar ele mais enxuto depois de pronto (sem as quebras onde elas "incomodam"). Se não quebrar linha entre os <li>, já resolve na origem, sem nunca entrarem no DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode remover excluindo os `nodeType 3`, que representam nós de texto (inclusive os espaços), mas isso também removerá textos caso houver.

Para isso pode-se usar `.contents().filter()`:

```js
$('#teste').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="teste">
    <img src="http://unsplash.it/100/100" alt="">
    <img src="http://unsplash.it/100/100" alt="">
    <img src="http://unsplash.it/100/100" alt="">
    <img src="http://unsplash.it/100/100" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

a quebra de linha irá gera um espaço em branco no HTML em elementos inline-block, mas comentando irá resolver

```
<div>
 <img src="" alt=""><!--
--><img src="" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: hahaha gambeta master essa, mas ta valendo

Comment: +1, Do ponto de vista do DOM, esta é a unica resposta que faz sentido.das apresentadas até o momento. Outras alternativas seriam simplesmente omitir a quebra totalmente, e quebrar dentro do elemento em vez de fora.

Answer (score 3):

Uma outra forma de eliminar os espaços é setar `font-size: 0`, mas você terá que, se houver textos em *elementos-filhos*, redefinir o tamanho da fonte nesses elementos.

**Exemplo:**

```css
#teste{
   font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="teste">
    <img src="http://unsplash.it/100/100" alt="">
    <img src="http://unsplash.it/100/100" alt="">
    <img src="http://unsplash.it/100/100" alt="">
    <img src="http://unsplash.it/100/100" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: É eu tinha visto em algum lugar que isso resolvia mesmo, colocar float:left ou display:flex também resolve, mas considerei essas opções no critério "gambiarra" rss, a resposta com o JS resolve plenamente, aproveito para agradecer!