# Comportamento de uma lista inline-block com floats

Tags: html5, css3

Tenho uma lista com 3 itens, todos os itens estão se comportando como inline-block, contudo, dei ao primeiro e a o último item `float: right` e `float: left`, respectivamente.

A pergunta é, por que o item do meio (`box-2`) não foi sobre posto pelo item da esquerda já que ele está em um novo contexto?
Como continua sendo renderizado com background e tamanho de caixa?
Não era pra ele ser sopre posto pela `box-1` ?

```css
.caixa{
  width: 25%;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.box-1{
  background: #F54958;
  float: right;
}

.box-2{
  background:#ED49F5;
  float: left;
}
.box-3{
  background: #EB5A46;  
}
```

```html
<ul class="lista">
  <li class="caixa box-1">Primeiro</li>
  <li class="caixa box-2">Segundo</li>
  <li class="caixa box-3">Terceiro</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Acho que a sua dúvida  talvez seja pq vc não entendeu o que seria o `display: inline-block;`... `Inline-Block` significa que o elemento é `inline` em relação aos irmãos, porém, por dentro ele se comporta como `block`.

Então por ter um *outset* de elemento `inline` ele respeita e segue o *flow* de texto, somo um `span`. Porem, o *inset* dele é `block`, ele pode receber propriedade de um elemento `block` como `width` e `height`.

Veja o caso do span mesmo

```css
span {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<span>inline</span>
<span style="display:inline-block">inline-block</span>
```

Essa pergunta tb  pode te ajudar a entender algumas coisas relativas e `float` e `inline-block` [Float vs. inline-block. Quais as vantagens e desvantagens de cada um?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/332116/float-vs-inline-block-quais-as-vantagens-e-desvantagens-de-cada-um)